# Whats up with this google url?

Tags: php, url, search-engine

So I know a little bit of PHP, and while I was making custom search links I realized that today google's url after searching something like "hi" isnt just

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=hi
```

instead its this

```
http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=hi&pbx=1&oq=hi&aq=f&aqi=g5&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1705l1911l0l2131l2l2l0l0l0l0l173l299l0.2l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=6c03fc000f912511&biw=1366&bih=681
```

Just wondering if someone has some insight as to what kind of info the rest of the url is passing along

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some examples of the data passed along:

```
hl=en #Locale: english
source=hp #Source: homepage
q=hi #Query: hi
```

In general, it's just whatever extra data that Google wishes to capture or pass along. As you've probably noticed, it's not required data in the sense that `http://www.google.com/search?q=query` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd one is likely an addressing string.  This is often used for navigating without full page loads.  This way a user can press the back button without going back to a previous url.

Answer (score 1):

If you notice, outside of all the parameters passed, the real difference is:

```
www.google.com/#
```

vs:

```
www.google.com/search?all_the_name=values&
```

The first example there is no page defined, the pound symbol tells it to stay where it is. Google has a feature that loads the results as you type (not the auto suggest) but the entire page. I can't seem to find how to trigger this though.